# Azure Java ServiceBus Queue Java receive or complete messages in batch for better performance

Tags: azure-servicebus-queues, azure-java-sdk

I am trying to receive messages from a queue and had experimented with different methods and was facing performance issues. Below are the metrics for each type of run:

- Receive Mode = peek and lock; 1000 messages took 2.5 minutes as I had to complete each message one by one
- Receive Mode = receive and delete; 1000 messages took an average of 1.5 mins.
- Receive Mode = receive and delete (with prefetch count as 100); 1000 messages took 3 seconds but I ended up losing the 100 messages which were in the buffer at the time of execution end
- Receive Mode = peek and lock (with prefetch count as 100); 1000 message took 2 minutes as I had to again complete each message. It would have been a problem solver only if there was a way to complete them in batch.

Below is my code for reference:

```
ServiceBusSessionReceiverClient sessionReceiverClient = new ServiceBusClientBuilder()
            .connectionString(System.getenv("QueueConnectionString"))
            .sessionReceiver()
            .maxAutoLockRenewDuration(Duration.ofMinutes(2))
            .receiveMode(ServiceBusReceiveMode.PEEK_LOCK)
            .queueName(queueName)
            .buildClient();
ServiceBusReceiverClient receiverClient = sessionReceiverClient.acceptSession(System.getenv("QueueSessionName"));
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    do {
        receiverClient.receiveMessages((int) prefetchCount).stream().forEach(message -> {
            try {
                String str = message.getBody().toString();
                final T dataDto = objectMapper.readValue(message.getBody().toString(), returnType);
                dataDtoList.add(dataDto);
                receiverClient.complete(message);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                AzFaUtil.getLogger().severe("Message processing failed.  Error: " + e.getMessage() + e + "\n Payload: "
                            + message);
            }
        });
    } while (dataDtoList.size() < numberOfMessages);
receiverClient.close();
sessionReceiverClient.close();
```

Possible solutions that I can think of:

- If there is a way to complete messages in batch instead of completing 1 by 1.
- If there is a way to requeue the messages back to the queue which are sitting in the prefetch buffer.

**Note: This API needs to be Synchronous. I just experimented with 1000 entries but I am working with 30000 entries so performance matters. Also the queue is session enabled and also partition enabled**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/23776), Microsoft has yet to test the performance of their ServiceBus. As FIFO (First In First Out) was a requirement for my message queue, I used JMS and it performed almost 10x faster on average but there is a drawback. Currently, JMS doesn't support session-based queues so I had to disable sessions, and then to ensure FIFO I also had to disable partitioning on the queue. This is a partial and temporary solution for better performance till either Microsoft improves the performance of their ServiceBusRecieverClient or enables sessions on JMS.